# Hide parent div when second child div is empty

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a structure like this:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child1">Header</div>
   <div class="child2">
      <div class="grandchild"></div>
      <div class="grandchild"></div>
      <div class="grandchild"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

So I want to hide the parent div when .child2 is empty.
I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
$(".child2:empty").parent().hide();
```

Am i doing something wrong? Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v5zbz05j/) that I have put up.

**EDIT:**
I want to clarify that rather than .child2 being empty the children divs of .child2 would be on display:none. I have editted my fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v5zbz05j/2/)

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/v5zbz05j/1/) second one is empty. In CSS4, for your case, you could use [:blank](http://css4-selectors.com/selector/css4/blank-pseudo-class/)

Comment: What do you mean `empty`? Hasn't text or hasn't child?

Comment: @Mohammad by empty i meant when the child of .child2 are on display:none. therefore visually the parent div would be empty.

Comment: Use `$(".child2:has(:hidden)").parent().hide()`. Check https://jsfiddle.net/v5zbz05j/4/

Comment: @Mohammad it would match if only on child is hidden but some others not, so not what asking OP

Comment: @A.Wolff I think `$(".child2:has(:not(:visible))")` is better.

Comment: @Mohammad This is same behaviour just less readable

Comment: @A.Wolff It would match if all child is hidden.

Comment: @Mohammad But not only. OP asks to match if **all** children are hidden, not just some of them. Anyway, regarding is former question and edit, this is really badly asked question...  See there: https://jsfiddle.net/1ttxeq9z/2/

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var childDiv = $(".child2");

    if(childDiv.html() == ""){
        childDiv.parents().hide();
    }

});
```

Comment: No, this is same behaviour as using `:empty`.  EDIT: in fact it is even more wrong because `html()` returns only the content of the first matched element in set

Comment: yes, of course, since the `$(".child2")` is having the `HTML` structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code does not work due to the whitespace between `<div class="child2">` and `</div>`. If you remove that whitespace your code works fine:

```js
$(".child2:empty").parent().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child1">Parent 1</div>
   <div class="child2">
      <div class="grandchild">GC1</div>
      <div class="grandchild">GC2</div>
      <div class="grandchild">GC3</div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
   <div class="child1">Parent 2</div>
   <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

If you cannot edit the HTML to remove the whitespace, then you can use `filter()` and `children()` instead:

```js
$(".child2").filter(function() {
    return $(this).children().length == 0;
}).parent().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child1">Parent 1</div>
   <div class="child2">
      <div class="grandchild">GC1</div>
      <div class="grandchild">GC2</div>
      <div class="grandchild">GC3</div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
   <div class="child1">Parent 2</div>
   <div class="child2">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But the div could contains only textNodes   https://jsfiddle.net/1ttxeq9z/  You should trim instead its html content

Comment: @Rory does this also apply for when children of .child2 are on display:none rather than it being empty.

Comment: @flolaloop no, in that case they would be counted. If that's a requirement, please include it in the question

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.each($(".child2"),function(){
   if($(this).children().length==0)
   {
     $(this).parent().hide();
   }
});
```

Comment: What about div containing only textNode?!  https://jsfiddle.net/1ttxeq9z/

Answer (score 0):

You should trim HTML content:

```
$(".child2").filter(function() {
    return !$(this).html().trim();
}).parent().hide();
```

Your issue is that your DIV contains some whitespaces. In CSS4, this would work using [:blank](http://css4-selectors.com/selector/css4/blank-pseudo-class/) pseudo-class.

**EDIT:** to check if the div only contains hidden children (or no displayed content), yo could check for its scrolling height:

```
$(".child2").filter(function() {
  return !this.scrollHeight;
}).parent().hide();
```

But most sure way would be:

```
$(".child2").filter(function() {
  return $(this).children().length === $(this).children().filter(':hidden').length;
}).parent().hide();
```